# Java cast int to char doesn't work

Tags: java, casting, char, int

I use Java 7 SE on Win7 Pro and have this problem:
Converting int to char doesn't work properly.

What is wrong?

Thanks.

```
int oneInt = 1;
char oneChar = '1';

// prints false
System.out.println((char) oneInt == oneChar);

// prints this symbol 
oneChar = (char) 1;
System.out.println(oneChar);

// Works - it prints 1 
oneChar = (1 + "").charAt(0);
System.out.println(oneChar);
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong, it's called ASCII brah

Comment: Read about Java Types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: `(int) '1'` is 49 as per the ASCII table, what did you expect `(int) '$'` to be?

Comment: I was confused about it and didn't know that the expressions `(char) intVal` and `(int) charVal` the equivalents for `AscW(intVal)` respectively `ChrW(charVal)` e.g. in VB are. Now it is clear as bellow mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using some static method built into the standard Java libraries.

For example, Integer.parseInt(String s) would take the string s and attempt to translate it to an integer. So Integer.parseInt("5") would return 5 as an integer.

String.valueOf(int i) would turn the integer into its String equivalent. So String.valueOf(10) would return "10" as a string.

If you're actually using chars and not just strings, this might help out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

There's methods like getNumericValue and isDigit. Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, but it might be cleaner than using magic numbers like adding 48 to get the char you're looking for.

Comment: In this particular case I was asking for the opposite direction: int -> char.
If I have to work with String, I'd prefer `oneChar = (1 + "").charAt(0);`. The above solution `oneChar = (char)(1 + '0');` of resueman is though shorter.
To convert int to String, I'd use normally e.g. `tenStr = 10 + "";` because it is short. However I don't know if it has a drawback?

Comment: Well, if you're using strings, I would suggest using String.valueOf because it handles the conversion for you and is (I think) more idiomatic of Java.

In the case of `oneChar = (1 + "")`.charAt(0)` I think what's actually happening is that the int 1 is being converted to a String when the empty string ("") is concatenated to it. Then you're specifically parsing out the first character of the String (which is basically a char array). The problem is that you have to know how many digits are in the number you want which results in brittle code.